# How to download a file from azure adls gen 1 to my local using java sdk?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

How to **download** a file (or an entire directory) from **adls gen 1** to my local using **Java SDK**?

There are plenty of examples on how to upload, read, delete, rename files etc. However, I fail to find documentation on how to download the files using *ADLStoreClient* object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are plenty of examples on how to upload, read, delete, rename
> files etc. However, I fail to find documentation on how to download
> the files using ADLStoreClient object.

Yes, there is no way to download and generate files directly. But you can already read the content of the file(`getReadStream()`) and get the metadata information(`getDirectoryEntry()`), and you can use these two things to generate a corresponding file locally.